# Kendo UI Jquery Grid does not work in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using sample from Kendo site to bind and show data in grid. Same works fine in other browser but does not work in IE 8. My Kendo version is v2019.1.220.

It throws "Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'" exception.

What could be the issue? Is kendo version not supported in IE 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 is indeed not supported by Kendo v2019.1.220.

In fact, IE8 is no longer supported as of the Kendo UI 2017 R1 release, as written in the documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/browser-support#notes-on-web-browser-support).